# Regex String Slicing

Tags: python, regex, slice

I am using Python flavor if regex, and I need to slice a string while replacing text. The regex I am using to match my needed string is this, `abc .+ cba`. If it matched `abc Hello, World cba`, that should change to `efg Hello, World`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a capturing group:

```
>>> s = "here is some stuff abc Hello, World cba here is some more stuff"
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'abc (.+) cba', r'efg \1',s)
'here is some stuff efg Hello, World here is some more stuff'
>>>
```

Note: the replacement string accepts a backreference.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function re.sub as below:

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

In repl, support use \1, \2 ... to backreference the string matched in pattern by group 1, 2 ..., using (). For this time, it's (.+)

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"abc (.+) cba",r"efg \1", "abc Hello, World cba")
'efg Hello, World'
```